# Animation moves just on first button click

Tags: java, android

I have one question.
I have a button ant when I click on it, imageView (with `objectAnimator`) goes down. I have my ˝animation down˝ in `onClick` and every thing is very simple, I click on the button and image goes down - there I have a question.

First, there is my code:

```
ObjectAnimator objectAnimatorBlock1 = getDownObjectAnimator(imageBlock1);
    animatorSetBlock1 = new AnimatorSet();
    animatorSetBlock1.play(objectAnimatorBlock1);
    animatorSetBlock1.start();

private ObjectAnimator getDownObjectAnimator(View v) {
        ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "translationY", 0.0f, 860.0f);
        objectAnimator.setDuration(2000);
        return objectAnimator;

and XML:


<ImageView
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_description"
        android:layout_marginRight="202dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="202dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-155dp"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageBlock1"
        android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/distance11" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:onClick="countIN"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_height="61dp"
    android:text="DROP THE BLOCK"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/layout100"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold|italic" />
```

My problem is: First time when I click on the button, image goes down and there also stand still(that is correct), but I would like that image goes down JUST when I first time click on a button. After first click animation is clear(finish animation) - then on second, third, fourth,... click , there is not any effect on image(it do not move). How can I do these?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AnimationUtils` instead of `ObjectAnimator`. You can write your animation in xml and store it in the `R.anim` folder. Then, you can apply it to the button's onClick listener as follows:

```
//image is your ImageView
button.setOnClickListener( 

...

//Suppose your animation is saved as moveDown.xml
Animation moveDown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext, R.anim.
image.startAnimation(moveDown);

...

});
```

This will make your ImageView (`image`) perform the animation each time you click the button. I hope this helps you out.